# What popular websites that are using Microsoft AppFabric?

Tags: caching, memcached, appfabric-cache

Our e-commerce web application was built on Microsoft technologies (asp.net mvc 4 & ms sql server) and it uses asp.net caching mechanism to store objects in memory. The issue with this is when the webApp restarts, say we deployed a DLL, it re-caching all objects so the webApp starts very slow.

To solve this issue, I'm currently looking at memcache for .net and MS AppFabric.

In http://memcached.org, there is a list of users which includes Flickr, Twitter, Youtube which makes me feel its really a solid & stable caching system.

What popular websites that are using Microsoft AppFabric as their distributed caching system?